# Get current index in a array-validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I got an input that contains an array of objects. Now I'd like to validate it, but one part of the validation depends on another item of the object, so I need it's index:

```php
[
    'items.myarray.*.owner_id' => 'numeric|exists:App\Models\Owner',
    'items.myarray.*.key'      => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:20', 'max:20', 'exists:App\Models\Invitation,key',
                           new KeyIsValid(Owner::findOrFail(request()->input('items.*.owner_id')))],
];
```

Of course `request()->input('items.myarray.*.owner_id')` is not working - but I am looking for a way to pass the `owner_id` of the current object to this validation.

Answer (score 1):

This will return an array value Try to use

```
$request()->input('items.myarray.*.key')[0]
```

it will return a string value of "**items.myarray.*.key**"
and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the the *, if your request contains $items['owner_id'], you can simply do `items.owner_id => 'validation-rules-here'`

Comment: Each entry of the array can have different `owner_id`s, so unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. But I see your point, in my initial question this was not clear.